# For Loop in Batch File Renames One File Twice

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, file-rename, batch-rename

I wrote this batch file to append some text to the filenames of a set of jpeg files, giving the option to append them before or after the current filename.

But for some odd reason when appending before the filename, one file is being proccessed twice getting the result as new_new_FileName.jpg while all other files are getting just new_FileName.jpg.

Interesting enough, this problem isn't happening always, as well as when appending after the filename it is always working fine.

Following is the entire code, with no visual difference between the before or after, but still resulting differently. Can anyone please examine this file and explain me where I'm wrong?

Help is appreciated.

```
@ECHO off
title Rename Script
set /A count=1
:Start
cls
set /p STR=choose a string to append:
cls
echo 1. Append before
echo 2. Append after
set /p choice=I choose (1,2):
if %choice%==1 goto renameb
if %choice%==2 goto renamea
:renameB
cls
echo Appending '%STR%' before current file name.
echo.
set /A count=0
FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO (
    ren "%%~a" "%STR%%%~na%%~xa"
    echo Was: %%~a Became: %STR%%%~na%%~xa
    set /A count+=1
)
goto end
:renameA
cls
echo Appending '%STR%' after current file name.
echo.
set /A count=0
FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO (
    ren "%%~a" "%%~na%STR%%%~xa"
    echo Was: %%~a Became: %%~na%STR%%%~xa
    set /A count+=1
)
goto end
:end
echo[
echo %count% files were renamed.
echo[
echo The process in now done.
pause
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for **renaming**, the simple `for` loop doesn't work:

```
FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO (
```

for some reasons from the old CP/M days with the [FCB's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_control_block) a `for /f` loop is needed:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.jpg') do (
```

Comment: it works fine for the after renaming, as well as for renaming before, just not always.
Would you please elaborate on what functionality '/f "delims="' adds to my code? As well as what the directory characters you used in your example refers to? Thanks.

Comment: With my first line in previous comment, I referred to my code.
Just tried with your solution and works perfect, just wondering what exactly is it saying, as well as how do I point him to a different folder. Thanks for your help.