# Windows batch to add prefix to file names, why added twice?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, batch-processing, prefix

In order to add a simple *"hello"* prefix to all pdf files in a folder I'm using this batch file:

```
FOR %%F IN (*.pdf) DO (RENAME "%%F" "hello%%F")
```

Saved this into a "rename.bat" file and placed it into the folder I need the files to be renamed. Then I just double click on "rename.bat".

This almost works but the 1st file gets the prefix added twice.

Let's say in the folder I have: A.pdf, B.pdf, C.pdf, they get converted into:

- **hellohelloA.pdf**
- helloB.pdf
- helloC.pdf,

Do you know what's wrong in the batch file?

---

I noticed it always does this when **files are more than one**. It works ok when there is only one file in the folder, but it is not very useful :-).

Comment: Use DIR /B and pipe the list of names to a text file. Then iterate though that list. Currently you are iterating though the folder while you are making changes in that folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [For Loop in Batch File Renames One File Twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519458/for-loop-in-batch-file-renames-one-file-twice)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`/f`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) removes the issue of recapturing an existing file:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR /a-d /b *.pdf')  DO (RENAME "%%F" "hello%%F")
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I read about `/F "delims="`, and I see you are also calling the command `'DIR /a-d /b *.pdf'`. But could you please explain why mine does not work. In order to test I even tried to call in batch file `FOR %%F IN (*.pdf) DO (ECHO "%%F")` and it echoes only 3 files, so do you know why when using `RENAME` in place of `ECHO` it's renaming the 1st file twice?

Comment: RENAME changes the list of files your working through, echo does not

Comment: `FOR %%F ...` get file names one by one from the disk directory so if the directory change, the names that FOR gets also _may_ change, although this depends on several factors. `FOR /F %%F ... in ('DIR') ...` _first_ execute the DIR command and _then_ get file names from the list generated by it. Note that /F form requires to execute a second copy of cmd.exe in order to execute the DIR command and also create a temporary file that is deleted at end.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
echo.
echo. Add Whatever Prefix...
echo.
echo. You Want To Add...
echo.
echo. To The Filename...
echo.
set /p variable=" > "
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir /b /a-d *.pdf') do (
  set oldName=%%a
  Set newName=%variable%!oldName!
  Ren "!oldName!" "!newName!"
)
exit
```

This works well..... Try It Out ...   No Double Prefix... Ever.